# setInterval just runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, fadein, setinterval

I have a lot of images inside `#imacon` and I want all images appear randomly but just appear 1 image. How might I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var leng = $('#imacon').children().length;
    var rm = Math.floor(Math.random()*leng);

    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#imacon img:eq('+rm+')').fadeIn();
    }, 500)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the random number after (or before) each image is changed.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        var leng = $('#imacon').children().length;

        setInterval(
            function() { 
                var rm = Math.floor(Math.random()*leng);
                $('#imacon img:eq('+rm+')').fadeIn();
            },
        500);

    });
```

Comment: Why not just calculate `rm` once before it's used rather than have the same line of code copied twice?

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is running every `500ms`, however you are fading in the *same* image every time. You need to get a random number inside the `setInterval` function. Try this:

```
var leng = $('#imacon').children().length;
setInterval(function() { 
    var rm = Math.floor(Math.random() * leng);
    $('#imacon img:eq(' + rm + ')').fadeIn();
}, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

how do you expect show an already shown image? you must `.hide()` all images before you fade in a random image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var leng = $('#imacon').children().length;

        setInterval(
            function() { 
                var rm = Math.floor(Math.random()*leng);
                $('#imacon img').hide();
                $('#imacon img:eq('+rm+')').fadeIn();
            },
        500);

    });
```